# In Console when I am click the input button with blank field I am getting an error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript and I am trying to make a table which will give us the result.

[My fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sibasish55/yLhhrqa1/)

```
function showResult() {
    var viewResult = document.getElementById('demo');
    var inputOne = document.getElementById("studentName").value;
    var inputTwo = document.getElementById("studentsubj").value;
    var stuName = studentName.indexOf(inputOne);
    var subName = subjectName.indexOf(inputTwo);
    var result = markes[stuName][subName];
    viewResult.innerHTML = "This is the marks of " + inputOne + " " + inputTwo + " " + result + " %";
}
```

In Console when I click the input button with blank input field I am getting an error in javascript

This is the error:

> "demo.js:408 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property '-1' of undefined"

What's wrong with my code.

Comment: what value did you entered in those input boxes?

Comment: In addition to the above comment, clearly the array `markes` is undefined with your way of access, You need to test whatever the values are empty or not.

Comment: .`indexOf()` returns -1 if the value isn't found. You need to test for that before trying to use the return value as an index into your array.

Comment: Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yLhhrqa1/2/

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the student and subject are exists.

```js
var studentName = ["Bruce", "Clark", "Barry", "Diana", "Victor", "Billy"];
var subjectName = ["English", "Math", "History", "Geography", "Physics", "Biology"];
var markes = [
    [99, 98, 97, 98, 99, 90],
    [98, 90, 96, 99, 98, 95],
    [95, 98, 94, 90, 97, 91],
    [99, 97, 94, 90, 96, 92],
    [69, 89, 79, 59, 65, 90],
    [50, 90, 91, 66, 70, 80]
];
function showResult() {

    var inputOne = document.getElementById("studentName").value;
    var inputTwo = document.getElementById("studentsubj").value;

    var stuName = studentName.indexOf(inputOne);
    var subName = subjectName.indexOf(inputTwo);

    if (stuName < 0) {
        alert("Student not found");
        return;
    }
    if (subName < 0) {
        alert("Subject not found");
        return;
    }
    var result = markes[stuName][subName];
    alert(result);
    document.querySelector('input').value = "";
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="auto">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>Math</td>
        <td>History</td>
        <td>Geography</td>
        <td>Physics</td>
        <td>Biology</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Bruce</td>
        <td>99%</td>
        <td>98%</td>
        <td>97%</td>
        <td>98%</td>
        <td>99%</td>
        <td>90%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Clark</td>
        <td>98%</td>
        <td>90%</td>
        <td>96%</td>
        <td>99%</td>
        <td>98%</td>
        <td>95%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Barry</td>
        <td>95%</td>
        <td>98%</td>
        <td>94%</td>
        <td>90%</td>
        <td>97%</td>
        <td>91%</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Diana</td>
        <td>99%</td>
        <td>97%</td>
        <td>94%</td>
        <td>90%</td>
        <td>96%</td>
        <td>92%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Victor</td>
        <td>69%</td>
        <td>89%</td>
        <td>79%</td>
        <td>59%</td>
        <td>65%</td>
        <td>90%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Billy</td>
        <td>50%</td>
        <td>90%</td>
        <td>91%</td>
        <td>66%</td>
        <td>70%</td>
        <td>80%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="studentName">
    <input type="text" id="studentsubj">
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="showResult()" />
</form>
<p id=demo></p>
```

The same code [HERE, Update for your link](https://jsfiddle.net/yLhhrqa1/3/)

Answer (score 0):

If the input field is blank `var stuName = studentName.indexOf(inputOne);` and `var subName = subjectName.indexOf(inputTwo);`
will return -1. so `var result = markes[stuName][subName];` will be `var result = markes[-1][-1];` This is the reason of console error.